# Access an object's EventListeners with Javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am using Tampermonkey to create a userscript on a forum I frequent.

The forum displays all in-line image(s) within a post like this:

`<a href='javascript:void(0);' title='image'>view in-line image</a>`

Then you have to click the 'image' link to view the image, and it loads in a new tab.

I want the userscript to display the image(s) in the post as an actual in-line image like:

`<img src='image_url' />`

I have no problem using the userscript to find and replace the `<a title='image'>` tags with `<img>` tags.

The problem is, I cannot get the **image_url** from each image link, and therefore cannot set the src tag.

The forum's javascript uses addEventListener for the Click event on the `<a title='image'>` links to set the image's URL. Therefore, the link's actual `href` value is `javascript:void(0)`, and the link doesn't include any other identifying filename tags (and title is always just 'image').

Is there any way I can access the EventListeners on these links, so I can extract the Click URL? Or can I somehow use Javascript/Tampermonkey to capture the resulting URL from the Click action?

Every other post I've read recommends using the browser's developer tools, but I need this to work from a userscript.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all event listener's associated with some element by using the function `getEventListeners(element)`, but I think you probably won't be able to scrape the image url's from the event listener.

Best of luck to you.